# how to add a different text box in input text type

Tags: html, css, forms, input, textinput

how to add a different text box and increased font in input text type using css as done in facebook?

i found this code on one of the site but thats not working please see if u can help me
i want to use rounded box in the form

```
.tb5 {
    background: url(images/rounded.gif) no-repeat top left;
    height: 22px;
    width: 230px;
}
.tb5a {
    border: 0;
    width:220px;
    margin-top:3px;
}
```

i want to use a rounded box as on https://www.facebook.com/ signup form instead of the default input box

Comment: Could you please explain more clearly what effect you're trying to achieve here? probably with help of some visual clues if possible..

Comment: Also please add a screen shot of the button you saw on fb.

Comment: sorry but thats the roblem only that much was available on that side here is a link to that  http://www.cssportal.com/form-elements/text-box.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style your text input using CSS:

```
input[type=text] {
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

You can also change other properties too, such as the border.

```
input[type=text] {
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

You can [check browser support over at caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius).

Comment: thanks its working absolutely fine on chrome but not working on IE but facebook uses the same thing at there it runs fine on both can u help with that sir

Comment: please sir i am quite new so please it would be really nice if u ca help me to understand this

Comment: border-radius is only available in IE9 and above.

Comment: yes i saw that but sir in the same browser its not working in mine but do work for fb

Comment: You can do it in older versions of IE by removing the border `border: none;` and adding background images that have the rounded corners: `background-image: url(roundedinput.png);`